# No enclosing instance of the type is accessible in scope

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(null, vieworders, "MagentoBackground");
thread.start();
m_progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SoftwarePassionView.this, 
    "Please wait...", "Retrieving data...", true);
```

This gives the following compilation error:

> No enclosing Instance of the type SoftwarePassionView is accessible in scope

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is this code inside the class `SoftwarePassionView` or sub-class of it?

Answer (score 11):

The expression `SoftwarePassionView.this` only makes sense if the code in the example snippet is found in a non-static inner / nested class, and one of the enclosing classes is `SoftwarePassionView`.  It says "give me the enclosing `SoftwarePassionView` *instance*".

If this code is not in that context, (as the compiler error would indicate), you need to replace the expression with a normal variable name, or method call that gives a reference to some `SoftwarePassionView` object.

---

For the record, here is an example where `SoftwarePassionView.this` wouldn't be a compilation error:

```
public class SoftwarePassionView {

    public class Inner {
        ...
        public void doIt() {
            Thread thread = new Thread(null, vieworders, "MagentoBackground");
            thread.start();
            m_progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SoftwarePassionView.this, 
                  "Please wait...", "Retrieving data...", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I honesty am not sure what you are saying. Would it be possible to get an example. and this is a non-static inner.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to get `this` for the enclosing class, which would work if you were inside an anonymous class, but I'm guessing this is not the case.

Please read http://mindprod.com/jgloss/this.html

Answer (score 4):

If you want to put your snippet inside a different class rather than SoftwarePassionView, you can pass an instance of the class SoftwarePassionView in your thread constructor.

Here is an example:

```
Class SoftwarePassionView {
  ....

  Thread thread = new something(SoftwarePassionView);
  thread.start();
  ......
  }
```

In the other class

```
 Class something extends Thread{
  SoftwarePassionView SPV;
  something(SoftwarePassionView){
  super(null, vieworders, "MagentoBackground");
  this.SPV = SoftwarePassionView}
  }

   @Override
public void run(){
    m_progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SPV, 
    "Please wait...", "Retrieving data...", true);
     }

  }
```