# Why can't I access outer class from inner Thread class in Java?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, scope

I have these class and its nested classes (please go to the relevant line):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Client {
  private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500, FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new ClientPanel());
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  private static class ClientPanel extends JPanel {
    JTextArea textArea;
    JTextField textField;
    JButton goButton;

    private ClientPanel() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      textArea = new JTextArea();
      add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      textField = new JTextField();
      add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      goButton = new JButton("Go");
      add(goButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
      goButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          textArea.append("Go button pressed. Text in field: "
              + textField.getText() + "\n ");
        }
      });
    }

    private static class GetBinaryThread extends Thread {
      private String data;

      public GetBinaryThread(String data) {
          this.data = data;
      }

      public void run() {
        try {
          ClientPanel.this.textArea.append(", recieved" + data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The compiler gives me an error on line:

```
ClientPanel.this.textArea.append(", recieved" + data);
```

> No enclosing instance of the type `Client.ClientPanel` is accessible in scope

How am I able to access the JTextArea of the outer class?

Comment: Reopened on the grounds that the other question doesn't have the complete example that this does - we can *definitely* tell what's wrong here, and the other question doesn't make that clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No enclosing instance of the type is accessible in scope](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5439241/1768232)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your nested class is a *static* nested class:

```
private static class GetBinaryThread extends Thread
```

Therefore it doesn't have an enclosing instance.

Get rid of `static` and then it'll be an inner class, with a reference to an instance of `ClientPanel`. Note that when you create an instance of `GetBinaryThread` (which you don't in the code you've shown) you'll need to have a `ClientPanel` reference to implicitly pass to the constructor as context.

Comment: @durron597: Where does the duplicate indicate that the OP's nested class was declared as `static`, and that that was the problem? It's easy to overlook unless it's pointed out. I'd argue that it would be more useful to close the *other* question as a duplicate of *this* one as this one provides more context.

Comment: @durron597: I agree that there's more code here than would be ideal, but it's not *that* much to sort through (116 lines) - I've seen a *lot* worse, and the question does also include the error message and where it occurs. Much better than far too little code, as is the case in the other question.

Comment: I'm sure you have seen much worse. I removed a lot of the junk and some of the more obvious swing mistakes.