# No enclosing instance of the type TObjectHash<T> is accessible in scope. Spigot plugin

Tags: java, plugins, error-handling, minecraft, bukkit

As I load the Server, the console gives this only error to enabling the plugin.

> No enclosing instance of the type TObjectHash is accessible in scope

Then after that there is a reference to the spigot plugin

> at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [spigot.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]

This TObjectHash is from the trove repository the following code is this inside the file:

```js
package gnu.trove.impl.hash;

import gnu.trove.impl.hash.TObjectHash;
import gnu.trove.strategy.HashingStrategy;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;

public abstract class TCustomObjectHash < T >
  extends TObjectHash < T > {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 8766048185963756400L;
    protected HashingStrategy <? super T > strategy;

    public TCustomObjectHash() {}

    public TCustomObjectHash(HashingStrategy <? super T > strategy) {
      this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    public TCustomObjectHash(HashingStrategy <? super T > strategy, int initialCapacity) {
      super(initialCapacity);
      this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    public TCustomObjectHash(HashingStrategy <? super T > strategy, int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
      super(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
      this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    @Override
    protected int hash(Object obj) {
      return this.strategy.computeHashCode(obj);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean equals(Object one, Object two) {
      return two != REMOVED && this.strategy.equals(one, two);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
      out.writeByte(0);
      TObjectHash.super.writeExternal(out);
      out.writeObject(this.strategy);
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in ) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException { in .readByte();
      TObjectHash.super.readExternal( in );
      this.strategy = (HashingStrategy) in .readObject();
    }
  }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Attention! This isn't JavaScript! It's Java. Java is to Javascript as car is to carpet.

Comment: Is this a plugin you're writing? If so, you must provide some code of your plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This type of question has been answered numerous times over the years

- [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)
- [No enclosing instance of the type is accessible in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439241/no-enclosing-instance-of-the-type-is-accessible-in-scope)
- [No enclosing instance of type Server is accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901941/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-server-is-accessible)
- [No enclosing instance of type... in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117072/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-in-scope)
- [Accessing Local Variables of the Enclosing Scope...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing)